# Thank you for celebrating 10 years of Ask Ubuntu!

Tags: discussion, community, 10th-anniversary

Just posting to say a big thank you to everyone for participating in the 10th anniversary celebrations and making it fun and awesome.

Acknowledgements:

For teaching classroom sessions, huge thanks and a round of applause to [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel) and [Artur Meinild](https://askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild) for sharing your knowledge.

For joining and supporting classroom sessions, deep gratitude to [BeastOfCaerbannog](https://askubuntu.com/users/618353/beastofcaerbannog), [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan), [αғsнιη](https://askubuntu.com/users/283843/%ce%b1%d2%93s%d0%bd%ce%b9%ce%b7), [Artur Meinild](https://askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild), [jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino), [user.dz](https://askubuntu.com/users/26246/user-dz), [technastic_tc](https://askubuntu.com/users/1103140/technastic-tc), [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon), [karel](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel), [Abhay Patil](https://askubuntu.com/users/1067851/abhay-patil) [SirGuelph](https://askubuntu.com/users/594579/sirguelph), [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy), [nobody](https://askubuntu.com/users/966203/nobody), [maria](https://askubuntu.com/users/11141/maria) and anyone else who attended (sorry if I missed you!) - you were all so helpful and nice.

Special thanks to [jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) for great help organising and running all the sessions, and to [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) for kindly reading several versions of my own lesson preparations and offering many corrections and improvements (for the remaining mistakes I take sole credit). Also, thanks a lot for creating transcript [bookmarks](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/113418/ask-ubuntu-classroom?tab=conversations) for the lessons (not my favourite job).

For organising the lovely [banner](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19340/527764), very grateful thanks to community manager [Catija](https://askubuntu.com/users/761293/catija). Thanks also to [Parto](https://askubuntu.com/users/163331/parto) for stepping up to help with the design, and sorry I wasn't able to organise that.

For creating the [What's your Ubuntu story?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19335/whats-your-ubuntu-story) post, thanks to [technastic_tc](https://askubuntu.com/users/1103140/technastic-tc). Thanks to all who have answered it to share their stories too.

For contributing ideas and support to make the celebration happen, thank you so much to [Mark Kirby](https://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby), [Dan](https://askubuntu.com/users/8698/dan), [jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino), [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy), [Nuwan Thisara](https://askubuntu.com/users/360794/nuwan-thisara), [Canadian Luke](https://askubuntu.com/users/89412/canadian-luke), [kashish](https://askubuntu.com/users/443229/kashish) [user3226932](https://askubuntu.com/users/304317/user3226932), [turbulence](https://askubuntu.com/users/1107236/turbulence), [Gopal S](https://askubuntu.com/users/1013762/gopal-s), [user203849](https://askubuntu.com/users/1127583/user203849), [user406875](https://askubuntu.com/users/1122646/user406875), [BeastOfCaerbannog](https://askubuntu.com/users/618353/beastofcaerbannog), [Pandya](https://askubuntu.com/users/256099/pandya), [Ravexina](https://askubuntu.com/users/264781/ravexina), [Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward) and [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander).

Thanks to all [the moderators](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) for general support and encouragement.

And thank you to you the community. Nothing can happen without y'all. <3<3<3

Comment: For teaching classroom sessions, huge thanks and a round of applause to *karel, Zanna and Artur Meinild* for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Zanna for a huge effort in arranging and assisting in this !! :-) :-)

Comment: A big thank you to everyone who participated. I am so sorry I wasn't able to join any class, that last month has been crazy.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks for the mention! I wanted to join in the classrooms, but it was a bit hard for me with other matters, unfortunately. But I'm going to be checking out the transcripts now that all classes are over, thank you all for making them easily accessible!

However, my main reason for adding an answer was not to excuse myself but to add one more name to the list that I strongly believe deserves a mention and an acknowledgement.

If you haven't guessed it yet, it's **[Zanna](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)**.

You did an amazing job organizing this! Your name can be listed in every paragraph in your post! Thank you for proposing, kickstarting, and organising the event!

Looking forward for the [20th-anniversary](/questions/tagged/20th-anniversary)!

Comment: :) <3 thanks a lot! I hope the classrooms will continue. I'll try to post something to encourage people to give more lessons any time. I'm also hoping to do a second series of my lessons some time in 2021.